# boost::gregorian::date_period representing all time

Tags: date, boost

Is there a way to build such an object?  This works, in practice:

```
date_period(date(1,Jan,1), pos_infin)
```

assuming you can assume that year 1 is effectively negative infinity.  But it seems like there must be a way to express an actually infinite time period.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you can do this:

```
date_period(date(neg_infin), pos_infin)
```